# Can't request to my Custom RPC with an Enum

Tags: polkadot-js, rpc

I'm trying to create a custom RPC for my pallet. I've followed Substrate Recipes (I know it's outdated but helped a lot) and `pallet_transaction` for Runtime API and RPC.

My first RPC, `profile_getSum`, works as expected. However, `profile_getProProfiles` has 2 params, and has an error when I try to request.

```
api.rpc.profile.getProProfiles("0x00", "toronto")
```

**What I've Tried:**

```
const profession = api.createType('ProfilePrimitivesProfession', 'None');
```

- `api.rpc.profile.getProProfiles("None", "toronto")`
- `api.rpc.profile.getProProfiles(profession.toHex(), "toronto")`
- `api.rpc.profile.getProProfiles(profession.toRawType(), "toronto")`

```
#[rpc]
pub trait ProfileStorageApi<BlockHash, Hash> {
    #[rpc(name = "profile_getSum")]
    fn get_sum(&self, at: Option<BlockHash>) -> Result<u8>;

    #[rpc(name = "profile_getProProfiles")]
    fn get_pro_profiles(
        &self,
        at: Option<BlockHash>,
        profession: Profession,
        area: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> Result<Vec<Profile<Hash>>>;
}
```

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, sp_core::RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum Profession { None, Doctor, Writer }
```

```
2022-03-04 16:51:15.760 TRACE ThreadId(82) rpc: Request: {"id":65,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"profile_getProProfiles","params":["None","0x746f726f6e746f"]}.    
2022-03-04 16:51:15.760 TRACE ThreadId(82) rpc_metrics: [ws] profile_getProProfiles call: MethodCall(MethodCall { jsonrpc: Some(V2), method: "profile_getProProfiles", params: Array([String("None"), String("0x746f726f6e746f")]), id: Num(65) })
2022-03-04 16:51:15.760 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker rpc_metrics: [ws] profile_getProProfiles call took 98 μs
2022-03-04 16:51:15.760 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker rpc: Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid length 4, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string with length of 64."},"id":65}.
```

**Update**

I've come across [Subsocial's node](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-node). Since it has similar RPC methods (having an enum parameter in the runtime-api) with mine it would be a good example.

Subsocial's [FlatPostKind enum](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-node/blob/6aea3c368afca13f7937def41a635735f066925e/pallets/posts/src/rpc.rs#L88-L94)

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Ord, PartialOrd, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum FlatPostKind {
    RegularPost,
    Comment,
    SharedPost
}
```

[RPC method](https://github.com/dappforce/subsocial-node/blob/master/pallets/posts/rpc/src/lib.rs#L24-L31)

```
#[rpc(name = "posts_getPublicPosts")]
fn get_public_posts(
    &self,
    at: Option<BlockHash>,
    kind_filter: Vec<FlatPostKind>,
    start_id: u64,
    limit: u16
) -> Result<Vec<FlatPost<AccountId, BlockNumber>>>;
```

As seen in the `fn get_public_posts`, it has a parameter that has a type of `Vec<FlatPostKind>`.

Still can't get a successful response. I believe it's not on `@polkadotjs/api` side but rather how I try to query.

```
burak@burak-pc:~$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":"2", "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "posts_getPublicPosts", "params":[["RegularPost"], "0", "1"]}' http://localhost:9934

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid type: sequence, expected a 0x-prefixed hex string with length of 64."},"id":"2"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [api docs of enums](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.basics#working-with-enums) is worth a review I think.
If your chain uses metadata v14, the metadata itself specifies the types completely, no need for manual definitions FYI, we highly suggest the update to include `scale-info` added [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8615). (Manual enum specification is there currently for historic blocks) Note you must annotate your enum to be included in the metadata, for [example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L210-L211):

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
pub enum PreimageStatus<AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber> {...}
```

I notice a mismatch in your `getProProfiles` api call and the `fn get_pro_profiles` declaration as well, 2 vs. 3 parameters. Likely just need to specify all uniformly before you try again? I *believe* `None` is explicitly needed in the api call if you are looking for the `Option` to be correctly sent over the wire.

Comment: I already use `scale-info`. I'm not looking to have `Option` in the enum. Basically, I need an enum parameter for filtering. `None` is needed for `Default`. I've edited the question for a more clear enum definition.

Comment: You're right. There are 3 parameters if you include `at: Option<BlockHash>` which I didn't. Passing `null` as the first parameter solved the issue.