# Custom RPC parameters

Tags: pallet, rpc, custom-rpc

I'm trying to return an item that is within a storageMap. Its key is a Vec(u8), but I don't know how to send this type using a curl call. I tried using the id as string and using its hex version and I receive de following message:

```
~ % curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "items_getItemById", "params": [1234321] }' http://localhost:9933

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32602,"message":"Invalid params: invalid type: integer `1234321`, expected a (both 0x-prefixed or not) hex string with length of 64."},"id":1}

~ % curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "items_getItemById", "params": [0x31323334333231] }' http://localhost:9933

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

This is the item stored on chain:

```
[
  [
    [
      1234321
    ]
    {
      id: 1234321
      summary: 12341234
      owner: 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
      state: ForSale
      price: 23
      lastUpdate: 1234123
      creationBlock: 4
    }
  ]
]
```

The main issue is that I'm not able to query the item from the following function:

```rs
pub fn get_item(id: ProductId) -> Option<ItemRpc> {
    Self::get_item_by_id(&id)
} 

fn get_item_by_id(id: &[u8]) -> Option<ItemRpc> {
    if let Some(value) = Self::items(id) {
        Some(value.to_rpc())
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

This is how I create items for the pallet:
[image: Creation entry point]

**UPDATE**

This is my rpc and my runtime api for the items pallet:

rpc:

```rs
fn get_item(
        &self,
        at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>,
        id: ProductId
    ) -> Result<Option<ItemRpc>> {
        let api = self.client.runtime_api();
        let at = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or_else(||
            // If the block hash is not supplied assume the best block.
            self.client.info().best_hash));

        let runtime_api_result = api.get_item(&at, id);
        runtime_api_result.map_err(|e| RpcError {
            code: ErrorCode::ServerError(9876), // No real reason for this value
            message: "Something wrong".into(),
            data: Some(format!("{:?}", e).into()),
        })
    }
```

runtime-api:

```rs
fn get_item(id: ProductId) -> Option<ItemRpc>;
```

node runtime:

```rs
impl_runtime_apis! {
    fn get_item(id: ProductId) -> Option<ItemRpc> {
        Items::get_item(id)
    }
}
```

ItemRpc struct:

```rs
pub struct ItemRpc {
        pub id: ProductId, // Vec<u8>
        pub summary: H256, // Vec<u8>
        pub owner: [u8; 32],
        pub state: State,
        pub price: Option<u32>,
        pub last_update: Timestamp, // Vec<u8>
        pub creation_block: u32,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few attempts, the only way to make it work was to supply an array of bytes but using ASCII encoding.

Example to query item with id '1234':

```
~ % curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "items_getItemById", "params": [null, [49, 50, 51, 52]] }' http://localhost:9933
```

After making this work, I was able to query multiple items (1234, 1762) providing a vector of bytes like

```
"params": [null, [[49, 50, 51, 52], [49, 55, 54, 50]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it answered [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/607/245). You need to add one more param for `Option<BlockHash>`

I believe you can try this,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "items_getItemById", "params": [null, 1234321] }' http://localhost:9933
```

Comment: I get the same errors :/ I have another rpc function that retrieves the first element of the storageMap and it works fine, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong or my functions are not getting the item correctly.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your rpc and runtime api code?

Comment: `id` is `Vec<u8>`, so you need to encode it as a hex string, as per the error message. Pass this via curl as the id `0x31323334333231`

Comment: @Jaco At the start of the post you can see that I also tried that. Now im getting the same issue even when working with u64 instead of Vec<u8>. Im passing as "params": [null, 1] and now it expects a sequence and not an integer :(

Comment: If you pass an encoded `Bytes`, you need to pass it explicitly quoted since it is a string, not a number. So this `"0x31323334333231"` is correct, this `0x31323334333231` is not. (This is why the node error refers to "hex string")